# Control Cursor Location on Focus in Form Field

Tags: javascript, django, onfocus

I have a form with 4 fields. I want the first of the four to have the `autofocus` and be the first the user fills out. But then, either by tab or mouse or whatever, when the user gets to second field, I want the cursor to end up at the end of the string to start. There is a pre-filled string in that field.

I'm using Django so I have a form widget controlling the attributes. I can get the string to show up and even get the cursor to the end, but this always causes `autofocus` as well on that second field. I haven't managed to get both.

Here is code I'm using so far:

**Django**

```
field = forms.URLField(
    widget = forms.URLInput(
        attrs = {
            'placeholder': 'enter field',
             # call to javascript function - this works
            'onfocus': 'add_string("field_id", "string")',
        } 
    )
)
```

**JavaScript:**

```
// add string to element
function add_string(id, string) {
    var input = document.getElementById(id);
    input.value = string;
}
```

I've played around with various JS scripts but to no avail. I then found [`setSelectionRange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Input.setSelectionRange) and played around with this like so:

```
input.setSelectionRange(7, 7)
```

Where 7 would be end of the particular "string" in the `onfocus` JavaScript function call, but I could't get this to work...

Finally, I played around with some jQuery that looked like this:

```
// focus after string, no highlight
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $field = $("#field_id");
    var old_val = $field.val();
    $field.focus().val('').val(old_val);
});
```

But this did the same thing: brought initial focus to second field and brought cursor to the end.

Any idea how I can do this, get both `autofocus` on field one but get cursor to jump to end of pre-filled string of field two on it's focus? Might be a nice trick if I knew how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, you just need to fire your code when your form field is focused, instead of on document ready. In my tests it was necessary to add a zero timeout, because otherwise the field value remains selected:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $field = $("#field_id");
    $field.on('focus', function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            var old_val = $field.val();
            $field.val('').val(old_val);
        }, 0);
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p2xsq/)

Comment: @Ianzz, thanks, that is just what I needed... I find it odd that not more developers talked about this online; of course, I could have just used the wrong search terms but I spent at least a couple hours of solid searching and testing without encountering a good solution. What's more is that I see this behavior in the wild, so I knew it could be done ;-) Thanks again.

Comment: By the way, have you used the `setSelectionRange` much? I would think this technically should work for my application as well but I couldn't get it to do so...

Comment: See [JSFiddle demo using `setSelectionRange`](http://jsfiddle.net/p2xsq/1/) (tested only in Chrome)

Comment: Nice... You have quite the way with JS. Thanks for your help. Cheers.